# Use canon or third party digital camera in unity for ar-camera options

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, vuforia

I want to use canon or third party digital camera in unity for AR-camera options.
The only option available in "Camera Device" drop down is "USB Camera".
How can I get my device to appear in that list (External Canon Digital Camera)?
Refer attached image . 
I have connected canon EOS Camera but it is not displayed in the Camera Device drop down.
Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track - that is the correct spot to use a different webcam for Vuforia (I use a logitech webcam and it works fine).

The challenge is getting your specific camera to be recognized as a webcam by Windows, which will likely require third party software such as (http://sparkosoft.com/how-to-use-dslr-as-webcam).

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your answer  but i need the external camera not webcam

Comment: The software I mentioned should allow you to use your external camera as a webcam (so Vuforia can use it). Hope that helps!

Comment: @Jaydip i used sparkocam but it didn't work and it gives a black screen on play mode. could you find a proper way to do that. if so could you please share it.